# Where can I find the exit code of a GCE startup script?

Tags: bash, google-compute-engine

I mentioned on my last question that I found out all the relevant log file locations and commands here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript

My situation:

Startup script literally starts with "exit 69" for testing purposes.

Commands I run:

```
sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup
echo $?
```

Output:

> 0

Relevant contents of `/var/log/daemon.log` (repeating):

> Sep 19 15:15:32 api-0 startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
>   Sep 19 15:15:32 api-0 startup-script: INFO Found startup-script in metadata.
>   Sep 19 15:15:32 api-0 startup-script: INFO startup-script: Return code 69.
>   Sep 19 15:15:32 api-0 startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.

Is there a good way to get the return code in my script without parsing `/var/log/daemon.log` and hoping that it actually ended up there and that I won't grab the wrong one?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I have no experience with the script_runner thing but I kinda have a solution for you.

Implement an Exit() function in your script with the following content:

```
function Exit(code) {
    echo $code > /tmp/runner_code
    exit $code    
}
```

und just `cat /tmp/runner_code` after executing the script. 
Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I'm trying to cover all cases where something in the script fails where I don't expect it, outside of my "exit" statements. Does defining a new Exit function overwrite the default exit functionality? So for example, if a random unexpected command in the middle of the startup script crashes with exit code 5, will this function automatically step in and execute itself and write a 5 to the file?

Comment: you can override the exit function using 'alias' but only inside your script. Something like 'alias exit=''Exit'. But in any case, the script won't exit by itself unless you specify 'set -e' at the beginning. If you have it, then just remove it and the program will only exit when you want it to

Comment: Well, the point is, I don't have any exit statements in my script. And even if I did, I want to cover crashes that happen outside of the exit statements. I'm gonna add the "set -e" to the script too. So an alias would be useless for my case, I think.

Comment: My current alternative is just echoing the return code of the most important command in the startup script into a file, but I want exits and crashes to both provide a code.